# Recent changes on the TeX.SE website

Tags: discussion, design, new-features

This evening I have logged in and found some news on the site TeX.SE, for example on the explanations for closure of the questions. I also saw a new screen regarding the reopening of the questions previously marked with on hold.

[image]

What are others news on TeX.SE?

Comment: You and we have to take care of pronouns, and the license of your content has been changed. [Summary on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Very kind moderator Stefan I have read your comment but for me it is not very clear :-(.

Comment: There are official announcements, and the link above leads to background and discussion.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Ah, now it is more clear. Very good and thank you. If you want to put an answer or other I am happy to vote positively it.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz What is this problem that everyone is talking about between stackexchange and the community? I didn't understand anything, is there a short, simple and clear summary?

Comment: @AndréC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Moderator_removal

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you, there was a difference about gender pronouns. In other words, who is for and who is against in this story?

Comment: @AndréC Why don't you just click the footnotes on Wikipedia?

Comment: @HenriMenke I did, but all these links are really very slow to read and understand. Licensing stories are complicated just like gender stories....  That is why I am looking for a summary, if there is one, of course, in order to get a general idea of the problem, even if it means reading each link more precisely.

Comment: @AndréC tl;dr: SE has a new CEO (Joel has left) and is focussing on SO and making money. Meta has become a nuisance for the company (which now has a roadmap they are not discussing) and the other communities are not important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previously, different sites within the network may have had their own code base, even if it were subtle. Changes like this seem to bring sites like ours in-line with the rest of the network. This promotes consistency across sites and is far better for site improvements.

Most changes to the network are posted here: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/168244)